# How do I populate and XForms model with the value AND text of a Select1?

Tags: xforms

I'm pretty new to XForms, and I am having problems trying to find the solution to what seems like a relatively trivial problem.  I have a select1 control on my form, and I want to bind an item in my model to both the selected value and the selected text of the control, so that I can store both values when the form is submitted.

My model looks something like this:

```
<model>
<valueofselect/>
<textofselect/>
</model>
```

Could one of you XForms gurus please post a small example of how this can be achieved.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this:

- using xforms:setvalue to set the value of the `/model/textofselect` node;
- using xforms:bind with a [`calculate` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#model-prop-calculate) to set the value of the  `/model/textofselect` node dynamically.

### Example:

Here's a complete xforms form demonstrating the second solution. The first way would look similar, the most important part (the XPath) would be the same in both solutions.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
<head>
<title>Select1 - get value and label</title>
<xforms:model id="main-model">
    <xforms:instance id="data">
        <model xmlns="">
            <valueofselect/>
            <textofselect/>
        </model>
    </xforms:instance>
    <xforms:instance id="items">
        <items xmlns="">
            <item>
                <label />
                <value />
            </item>
            <item>
                <label>label a</label>
                <value>value a</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <label>label b</label>
                <value>value b</value>
            </item>
            <item>
                <label>label c</label>
                <value>value c</value>
            </item>
        </items>
    </xforms:instance>
    <xforms:bind
         nodeset="instance('data')/textofselect"
         calculate="instance('items')/item[value eq
                    instance('data')/valueofselect]/label/text()" />
</xforms:model>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Select...</h1>
    <xforms:select1 ref="instance('data')/valueofselect">
        <xforms:itemset nodeset="instance('items')/item">
            <xforms:label ref="label"/>
            <xforms:value ref="value"/>
        </xforms:itemset>
    </xforms:select1>
    <h1>Selection result</h1>
    <xforms:output ref="instance('data')/valueofselect">
        <xforms:label>Selected value: </xforms:label>
    </xforms:output><br />
    <xforms:output ref="instance('data')/textofselect">
        <xforms:label>Selected Value's label: </xforms:label>
    </xforms:output>
</body>
</html>
```

### Explanation:

The `xforms:bind` makes the XForms engine calculate the value of the `/model/textofselect` node depending on the value of the `/model/valueofselect` node. To do so, it selects the text value of the selected item from the items list using a XPath predicate.

To make the `select1` items accessible to the bind, they aren't defined as children of the `xforms:select1` node. Instead, they're put into the `xforms:model` using the [`xforms:itemset` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#ui-selection-commonelems-itemset).